# Scikit learn: which regressors natively support multi-target regression?

Tags: scikit-learn

[The docs on sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputRegressor](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputRegressor.html) state that it implements a strategy for extending regressors that do not natively support multi-target regression.

I'm interested to know: which ones do natively support multi-target regression ? (and/or how can I find out?)

based on [this article](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/plot_multioutput_face_completion.html), I assume:

ExtraTreesRegressor 
KNeighborsRegressor 
LinearRegression 
RidgeCV

All support this? (unless I'm getting confused and a 'multi-output estimator'  is not the same thing as 'a regressor that natively supports multi-target regression'; I'm new to this!)

Answer (score 1):

In scikit-learn, there is a [`MultiOutputMixin`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/95119c13af77c76e150b753485c662b7c52a41a2/sklearn/base.py#L758) class. So, you could check if the estimator inherits from that one.

Alternatively, you could use [estimator tags](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/develop.html#estimator-tags) and check if `{'multioutput': True}` is included in the tags of the estimator.